# Hooking functions which take multidimensional arrays

Tags: java, frida

I'm building an in-process JNI library fuzzer using Frida and I think I got everything to work except for multidimensional arrays.
When testing on Linux_64, I'm not able to even create a valid hook for a function which takes multidimensional arrays. No matter what I try I'm getting something like:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [L[I;
> at CallCrashingFun.crashingMethod_dbarr(Native Method)
> at CallCrashingFun.main(CallCrashingFun.java:100)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [I
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)

My hooking script looks similar to this:

```
var t_class = Java.use("CallCrashingFun")
var method_name = "crashingMethod_dbarr"
t_class[method_name].implementation = function(dbint) {
    console.log("Hook works!")
}

/* Also tried with params
t_class[method_name].overload.apply(t_class[method_name], param_types).implementation = function(dbint) {
    console.log("Hook works!")
}*/
    

/* This however doesn't crash
var imp_cp = t_class[method_name].implementation
t_class[method_name].implementation = imp_cp
*/
```

The Java code I use for tests:

```
System.loadLibrary("native");
int arr[] = {2,2,2};
int[][] dbarr = {arr};
new CallCrashingFun().crashingMethod_dbarr(dbarr);
private native void crashingMethod_dbarr(int[][] dbarr);
```

The JNI C++ code:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_CallCrashingFun_crashingMethod_1dbarr
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObject, jobjectArray dbtab) {
      int i, j;
      std::cout << "DbArray: " << "[" << std::endl;
      jsize len = (env)->GetArrayLength(dbtab);
      for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
         std::cout << "[";
          jintArray insArr = (jintArray) (env)->GetObjectArrayElement(dbtab, i);
          jsize inlen = (env)->GetArrayLength(insArr);
          jint *body = (env)->GetIntArrayElements(insArr, 0);
          for (j=0; j<inlen; j++) {
            std::cout << body[i] << ",";
          }
          std::cout << "]" << std::endl;
      }
      std::cout << "]" <<  std::endl;
  }
```

Java version that I'm using:

> $ /usr/bin/java --version
> Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
> openjdk 11.0.17 2022-10-18
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.17+8 (build 11.0.17+8)
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.17+8 (build 11.0.17+8, mixed mode)

Frida server version:

> frida-server-16.0.8-linux-x86_64

Without hook the function works correctly:

> DbArray: [
> [2,2,2,]
> ]

How can I get this hook to work?

Comment: If functions with multi-dimensional arrays as arguments are the only functions that don't work a bug in frida is possible. As you seem to have a test case I would recommend to open an issue at frida's github issue tracker and include the sample app you have created.